# checkbox django return all false

Tags: django, forms, checkbox

My checkbox always return False value
my model

```
ho_so_giu=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

my form

report_ho_so_giu = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'form-check-input'}),required=False)

in my html template I add more code in my html template

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <form method="POST" id = "form_save_report" name ="form_save_report" value="form_save_report">

    <div style="color:red;background-color:white">THÔNG TIN XỬ LÝ</div>
    <div class="row">
      {% csrf_token %}
      
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-4" id="labelsohd" name="labelsohd" style="display:none">Ngày hẹn</div>
            <div class="col-md-6" id="so_hd" name="so_hd" type="number" style="display:none">{{form.so_hd}}</div>
       <div class="form-group row">
         <div name={{form.report_ho_so_giu.name}} id ="form.report_ho_so_giu.auto_id"> {{form.report_ho_so_giu}} </div>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="{{form.report_ho_so_giu.auto_id}}">{{form.report_ho_so_giu.label}}</label>
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Dòng 3 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">               
            <div  class="form-group row">
                <div class="card-footer" >
                  <button type="submit" class="fa fa-save" style="font-size:20px; color:blue" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="submit" name="submit">Lưu báo cáo</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>

 
</div>
```

in my view, I add more code in my view

```
if request.method=='POST':
    #print("request POST")
    form=AddReportForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        
        #print("if form")
        so_hd=form.cleaned_data["report_so_hd"]
        
        print(request.POST.get("report_ho_so_giu")) # return None
        print(request.POST.get("id_report_ho_so_giu")) # return None

        print(request.GET.get("report_ho_so_giu")) # return None
        print(request.GET.get("id_ho_so_giu")) # return None

        print(form.cleaned_data["id_report_ho_so_giu"]) # return False with checked or unchecked
        print(form.cleaned_data["report_ho_so_giu"]) # return KeyError: 'report_ho_so_giu'

        daily_report=report(so_hd=so_hd, ho_so_giu=ho_so_giu)
        daily_report.save()
        report_response_data={}            
        report_response_data["so_hd"]=so_hd
        return JsonResponse({"so_hd":report_response_data["so_hd"],
        })
```

I am using ajax to return my value from form but it still return only on whenever I check or uncheck box

```
ho_so_giu =$('#ho_so_giu_text').val() //return on
```

I try to print the result it just return "None" or "False"  in my view, If I use console log in html file it retunr only "on". I read some question in stackoverflow and use some answer but it just return None or False
Is there any solution to replace checkbox in this case if I cannot find out the issue?

Comment: Share the full view and HTML form.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I add more code in my view and my html form template

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be with your form, try this:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['ho_so_giu']
        widgets = {
            'ho_so_giu': forms.CheckboxInput(
                'class': 'form-check-input', 
                'id': 'ho_so_giu_text', 
                'name': 'ho_so_giu_text'
            )
        }
```

Notes:

1. I dont know why you have given a name to the form. I have never seen that before. Could that be creating issues with the post request to the backend?
2. Have you tried building the form on the frontend by youserlf? Using just html? It would be a good way to debug the issue.
3. Consider writing a hybrid form, mostly in html, with dynamic elements. This will allow you to monitor exactly what's happening. Check out the example here below:

```
<input  name="{{ wc_user_form.last_name.name }}" type="text" class="form-control" id="{{ wc_user_form.last_name.auto_id }}" placeholder="Votre Nom" oninput="customValidation(this);" required>
<label for="{{ wc_user_form.last_name.auto_id }}">{{ wc_user_form.last_name.label }}</label>
```

Pretty cool eh? Pay particular attention to the `{{ form.field.auto_id }}` template tag. That - as you can imagine - generates the id of the field that the backend expects in order to perform a `form.save()`

Comment: Thanks for your teaching me this technique. I change my code as your suggest. Please see my edited question, I updated my code. But it still return None.

Comment: Have you tried:  `if form.is_valid():    form.save()` ?

Comment: Yes. I tried If form.is_valid(). Other values in form return exactly value, except checkbox.

Comment: Yes. I tried If form.is_valid(). Other values in form return exactly value, except checkbox.